# Zend/Session with ZfcUser

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-session, zfcuser

I'm using ZfcUser in my app and I need to control the timeout parameter. As it's not part of the configuration I would like to set my own Zend/Session object (with the `remember_me_seconds` param) to ZfcUser on bootstrap but I don't know how.

By chance, has anyone done this already?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to set session params is as follows
`config\autoload\global.php`

```
return array(
    'service_manager' => [
        'factories' => [
            // Configures the default SessionManager instance
            'Zend\Session\ManagerInterface' => 'Zend\Session\Service\SessionManagerFactory',
            // Provides session configuration to SessionManagerFactory
            'Zend\Session\Config\ConfigInterface' => 'Zend\Session\Service\SessionConfigFactory',
        ],
    ],
    'session_manager' => [
        // SessionManager config: validators, etc
    ],
    'session_config' => [
        'cache_expire' => 86400,
        'cookie_lifetime' => 86400,
        'remember_me_seconds' => 86400,
        'gc_probability' => 10,
        'gc_divisor' => 1000,
        'use_cookies' => true,
        'cookie_httponly' => true,
        'cookie_lifetime' => 0, // to reset lifetime to maximum at every click
        'gc_maxlifetime' => 86400,
    ],
);
```

And add line to `onBootstrap` method at `Module.php`

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $manager = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('Zend\Session\ManagerInterface');
}
```

This will affect session setting and `phpinfo()` shows it.

I found it in [zfcuser github](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/wiki/How-to-configure-a-session-timeout)

Answer (score 0):

I don't use zfcuser but try this

autoload/global.php

```
<?php

use Zend\Session\Config\SessionConfig;
use Zend\Session\SessionManager;
use Zend\Session\Container;

return array(
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'SessionManager' => function($sm) {
                $sessionConfig = new SessionConfig();
                $sessionConfig->setOption('remember_me_seconds', 1440);

                $sessionManager = new SessionManager($sessionConfig);
                Container::setDefaultManager($sessionManager);

                return $sessionManager;
            },
        ),
    ),
);
```

Module.php

```
public function onBootstrap($event)
{
    $serviceManager = $event->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
    $serviceManager->get('SessionManager')->start();
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid it is more complex than this. The session must be linked to ZfcUser in some way...

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it. I am not the worlds greatest coder but this seems to work. This is all in Module.php

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $sharedManager       = $eventManager->getSharedManager();
    $sm = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();        
    //This checks to see if the user is logged in. 
    $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, array($this, 'checkLogin'), 100);


}

//This function is attached to a listener to see if the user is not currently logged in
//If they are not logged in they will be redirected to the login page. This check will happen through the 
//application so there is no need to keep checking in other modules
public function checkLogin (MvcEvent $e)
{



    $session = new Container('defaults');        
    $this->route = $e->getRouteMatch();
    $this->matchedRouteName = explode('/', $this->route->getMatchedRouteName());
    $this->route_root = $this->matchedRouteName[0];
    $sm = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();

    $zfcServiceEvents = $sm->get('ZfcUser\Authentication\Adapter\AdapterChain')->getEventManager();

    $zfcServiceEvents->attach(
            'authenticate',
            function ($e) use ($session) {
            $session->offsetSet('sessionstart', $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']);
            }
    );  

    $auth = $sm->get('zfcuser_auth_service');

    if (!$auth->hasIdentity() && $this->route_root != 'zfcuser')
     { 
        $response = new \Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response();
        $response->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Location', '/user/login');
        $response->setStatusCode(302);
        $response->sendHeaders();
        $e->stopPropagation(true);
        return $response;
    }

   else if ($auth->hasIdentity() && $session->offsetGet('sessionstart') < ($_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] - 10800) && $this->route_root != 'zfcuser')
   {
        $response = new \Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response();
        $response->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Location', '/user/logout');
        $response->setStatusCode(302);
                $response->sendHeaders();
                $e->stopPropagation(true);
                return $response;
   }

   else if ($auth->hasIdentity())
   {
    $session->offsetSet('sessionstart', $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']);
   }    
}
```